# How can I resolve the issue when finding location in a sentence using Apache OpenNLP

Tags: java, apache, android-studio-3.0, opennlp

```
package com.example.dell.apacheopennlp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;
public class apacheOpenNLP extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_apache_open_nlp);
        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtView);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        TokenizerModel tokenModel =null;
        try{
            inputStream = getAssets().open("en-token.bin");
            tokenModel = new TokenizerModel (inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            txt.setText (e.toString ()+" inside catch of token");
        }

        if(tokenModel!=null) {
            TokenizerME tokenizer = new TokenizerME (tokenModel);
            String paragraph = "Tutorialspoint is located in Hyderabad";
            String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize (paragraph);
            InputStream locationInputStream=null;
            TokenNameFinderModel locationModel = null;

            try {

                locationInputStream = getAssets ( ).open ("en-ner-location.bin");
                locationModel = new TokenNameFinderModel (locationInputStream);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ( );
                txt.setText (e.toString ()+" inside catch of location");
            }

            if (locationModel != null) {
                NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME (locationModel);
                Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find (tokens);

                String result = null;
                for (Span s : nameSpans)
                    //result=  s.toString()+"  "+tokens[s.getStart()];
                    result += s.toString ( );
                txt.setText (result);
            }
            else{
               // txt.setText ("Location model is empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the apache OpenNLP to extract the location in a sentence. I have debug the code and found that after NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME (locationModel); the android app crash showing a message "The app has stopped working"
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException:java.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the nameFinder to be declared as TokenNameFinder interface type?

Just try to replace

```
NameFinderME nameFinder = null
```

with

```
TokenNameFinder nameFinder = null
```

Rest all should be same.